# commented out code causing runtime error in clojure

Tags: clojure, comments, geoip

context: I am writing a Cascalog job to run in Amazon EMR. Cascalog is a clojure based lib for running MapReduce. When the job fails due some a weird classloading exception.

In the job I use a lib called geocoder which is a clojure based geoip lookup lib. In particular I was using the part of the lib that looked at the maxmind GeoLiteCity.dat file. I found out that the the part of my code which caused the job to fail was the part that used the geocoder lib.**

the weirdest thing is that while removing this part of the code would cause the job to succeed, commenting out would not ... just wondering if anyone has any idea what is going on?

**
the way i used the geocoder lib like so

(ns utils.geoip (:use [geocoder.core]))

and then my job would require the above

(ns myjob (:require [utils.geoip :as geoip]))

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: All right, which class? Provide as much detail as possible.

Comment: sorry -- it gets a little involved here. originally the errors I were getting looked like this:
 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: views.visit-facts, compiling: 
(views/ 
visit_facts.clj:1) 
        at cascalog.Util.tryRequire(Util.java:61) 
        at cascalog.Util.bootSimpleFn(Util.java:65) 
        at cascalog.Util.bootFn(Util.java:72) 

originally I thought someone was going wrong w/r/t the hyphen vs underscore issue; in one test I changed the ns of my job from views.visit-facts to view.vf, but that just caused the same exception to come up some other classname with a underscore

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question possibly depends upon which technique you are using to comment out the offending code? i.e. are you using `;` or the multi-line `(comment foo)` macro?

The reason I ask is that whilst code commented out with `;` is completely ignored, the `comment` macro requires a syntactically correct S-expression as body; so a simple syntax error could be causing your unexpected error in code that you believe is being ignored.

To put it another way: The comment macro doesn't allow for arbitrary text.

Comment: Yea, the weirdest part is that I used ; because I knew the (comment ...) had that property about it

Comment: so its

`(geoip/get-ip-country !ip-address :> !ip-address)`
  
vs   
  
`;(geoip/get-ip-country !ip-address :> !ip-address)`